# Unwanted reevaluation in Manipulate with RandomPointConfiguration

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, dynamic, random

Here is a simple illustration of a problem I am encountering. I want to use `RandomPointConfiguration` inside `Manipulate`, but it usually evaluates twice. Consider the following four variations of a single example:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{pts = 
    BlockRandom[
     RandomPointConfiguration[PoissonPointProcess[n, 2], 
      Disk[]]]}, {Last@Date[],
   Show[RegionPlot[pts["ObservationRegion"]], ListPlot[pts]]}], {n, 1,
   500}]

Manipulate[
 Module[{pts = 
    RandomPointConfiguration[PoissonPointProcess[n, 2], Disk[]]},
  {Last@Date[], 
   Show[RegionPlot[pts["ObservationRegion"]], ListPlot[pts]]}], {n, 1,
   500}]

Manipulate[
 Module[{pts = 
    RandomPointConfiguration[PoissonPointProcess[n, 2], Disk[]]}, 
  SeedRandom[1];
  {Last@Date[], 
   Show[RegionPlot[pts["ObservationRegion"]], ListPlot[pts]]}], {n, 1,
   500}]

Manipulate[
 Module[{pts}, SeedRandom[1]; 
  pts = BlockRandom@
    RandomPointConfiguration[PoissonPointProcess[n, 2], Disk[]]; 
  SeedRandom[1];
  {Last@Date[], 
   Show[RegionPlot[pts["ObservationRegion"]], ListPlot[pts]]}], {n, 1,
   500}]
```

I have included `Date` to make clearer the second evaluation. There are always two evaluations when `n` is changed if I change `n` via the slider or via opening the slider and using the `+`/`-` buttons, but the time between them depends on which of these methods I use. You may have to wait to see the second evaluation. If, however, I change `n` via opening the slider and putting in a number, then there is only one evaluation.

How can this be fixed? I am also curious why this happens and what explains the peculiar dependency on how `n` is changed.

Comment: Does replacing `Module` with `DynamicModule` fix the problem?

Comment: @MarcoB No, it does not. I see no difference, although I tested only the first variation with your suggestion. Also, I see no difference between versions 13.3 and 13.0, although I tested only the first variation in 13.0.

Comment: Try adding `ContinuousAction -> False` as an option to the end of The `Manipulate`. I suspect the multiple updates may be due to Manipulate attempting to update on intermediate values as the value of $n$ changes then.

Answer (score 0):

I concentrated on the simpler form without `BlockRandom`, `SeedRandom`, and so on, because I don't think any of that is relevant here. I recommend that you add `ContinuousAction -> False` as an option to your `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[
   {pts = RandomPointConfiguration[PoissonPointProcess[n, 2], Disk[]]},
   {DateString[Now, "Millisecond"], Show[Graphics[Disk[]], ListPlot[pts]]}
 ],
 {n, 1, 500},
 ContinuousAction -> False
]
```

This will prevent evaluation while the cursor is moved / the value is changed. The continuous evaluation would also be responsible for multiple evaluations when dragging the slider, i.e. while you are dragging, plus one last one when you release the slider.

In the code above, replacing the slower `RegionPlot` with the faster `Graphics`, and replacing the `Date` expression with the more updated `DateString` call reporting high granularity millisecond results, helps with visualizing this.

Comment: This works for the slider, but does not change the behavior for the -/+ buttons.

Comment: @RussLyons It does for me. Once I press the +/- buttons on the control, I only get one update time. I am on MMA 13.3.0 on Win10-64

Comment: I have to wait for the second update, but it still occurs. I am on Linux using 13.3.0 or 13.0.1 (same behavior).

Comment: @RussLyons OK I see what you mean. I see that delayed final update as well. That is odd!